# DataGridView Doesn't show the dataTable that binded to it

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView in my project that working as my basket in the shop. When I select a commodity in my main DataGridView, the information of that commodity selected from my database and added to a DataTable object and the end my data table bound to my basketDataGridView, but in my project my basketDataGridView doesn't show the content of my dataTable.

You can see the below code.

**Note**: my `FrooshDataGridview` is my main Datagridview and the `nesyeBasketDataGridview` is my basket.

Thanks

```
    private void FrooshDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (FrooshDataGridView.RowCount > 0)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1 &&
                FrooshDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn)
                if (FrooshDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString().Trim() == "Add to Basket")
                    if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Are you shur that to add to basket ", "Add", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
                    {
                        int a = (int)FrooshDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value;
                        //MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
                        string sql = "select * From tblKala where ID =" + a.ToString();
                        da.SelectCommand.CommandText = sql;
                        conn.Open();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        conn.Close();
                        DataRow MyRow = table1.NewRow();
                        MyRow = dt.Rows[0];
                        table1.ImportRow(MyRow);

                    }
            //NesyeBasketDataGridView.DataSource = null;        

            //NesyeBasketDataGridView.Show();
        }
        NesyeBasketDataGridView.DataSource = table1; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, your `table1` should have the same structure with the local `dt`. If not, the row you copy from the `dt` to the `table1` will fill the column from left to right. To copy the structure from the table `dt`, you can use the `Clone` method like this:

```
table1 = dt.Clone();
```

Your code is wrong because that's not the way to copy a row, you can use the `ImportRow` directly like this:

```
table1.ImportRow(dt.Rows[0]);
```

Comment: Hi, your code do work but a new problem is happened. when I click the new button in my columns of button in my main dataGridView to add the basket , the new row overwrited in the existing row in my basketDataGridView , in other word i want to add new rows in my basket. Can you help me?

Comment: @user2936286 is your main DataGridView's DataSource the `table1`?

Comment: no , i have a table in my database that all of the commodity in the shop is registered in this table. i select all of the rows in my main DataGridView,. in my main dataGridView i have a columns of button that when the user click on one of them , that row imported to the 'tablel1' and the 'table1' binded to my basketDataGridview.

Comment: @user2936286 the code above of course will have new row to your basket, that row is imported from the first row of the `dt`, isn't that what you want? What do you mean by `the new row overwrited in the existing row in my basketDataGridView`? There is not any code relating to any row of your basketDataGridView, so it's confusing here.

Comment: Mr @King King my problem after asking one of my friends is solved. thanks a lot from your attention . Have a Good time :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try

```
table1.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray);
```

as replacement for the last three rows in your inner if statement ... didn't test it but could be worth a try ...